# Using findComponent on preRenderView listener

Tags: jsf

On the JSF page:

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{backingBean.test()}" />

<h:inputHidden id="inputHiddenId" value="dummy" />
```

On the backingBean:

```
public void test() {
    System.out.println("test");

    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    UIComponent comp = fc.getViewRoot().findComponent("inputHiddenId");
    if (comp != null) {
        System.out.println("comp " + comp); // Does not print
    }
}
```

The phaseListener shows that test() is called during render response phase:

```
START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
test
END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
```

However, it is not finding the inputHiddenId component. It seems that the component is not available during this time. Does it need to be on a postback? How can I access the component when first loading the page? Sorry, I am not too familiar with the intricacies of the JSF lifecycle. If anyone could shed some light on this, it would be greatly appreciated.

---

Reposting the problem:

The real problem is that I have a form with several fields. After the form is submitted, users can still edit certain fields which has the effect of resetting other sections on the form and making it invalid. Since it is a long form, users should be able to save the form even though it fails validation, and return to it later. So when loading the page, I'd like it to display inline validation on the fields. We are using JBoss Seam. The validation method displays the errors using

```
StatusMessages.instance().addToControl("inputHiddenId", severity, message)
```

The validation method is called from the page.xml using

```
<action execute="#{backingBean.pageInitWithValidation()}" on-postback="false" />
```

However this doesn't display the error message inline on the ui component

```
<s:div id="errorMessages">
    <h:inputHidden id="inputHiddenId" value="dummy" />
    <h:messages for="inputHiddenId" />
</s:div>
```

It shows it instead at the top in the global messages

```
<h:messages globalOnly="true" />
```

That's why I tried to use the preRenderView, but that had the same effect.

I'm currently using a second method with the body onload event along with a4j:jsFunction, but it is not very clean.

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="validate" 
    action="#{backingBean.validate()}" render="formId" />

<h:body onload="validate()">
```

Comment: I suggest to take a step back and ask how to properly solve a particular problem for which you incorrectly thought that this all would be the right solution. See also http://xyproblem.info. Any attempt to grab an UI component in a backing bean is a huge smell.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to give a filtered version of my actual problem for simplicity's sake. Sorry, I don't know how I should repost the problem, so I'm posting as part of the solutions. Feel free to edit. Thanks

Comment: It is in first place not clear which problem exactly you're trying to solve this way, so I couldn't fix your question. All I can do is posting the above comment and asking you to take a step back.

Comment: As per your edit, so something like `<h:messages ... rendered="#{facesContext.postback}">` should work for you? Or moving it to bottom of the component tree (and positioning it static/absolute via CSS) and using `redisplay="false"` instead?

Comment: I tried moving <h:messages globalOnly="true" /> to the bottom of the page, but the message still shows up there instead of inline with the component. In this case, I would like it to do the validation on page load not postback, so the message would have to be rendered not on postback. On reflection, the form validation may need to be handled another way. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510362/multi-tiered-jsf-validation-dependent-on-submit